# When using Xcode analysis (product>analyze) is there a way of ignoring any errors in a given file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, analysis

When using Xcode analysis (product>analyze) is there a way of ignoring any errors in a given file?

Eg a pragma or something?

We just want to ignore any warnings on third party code, so that it's more obvious to us when there's a problem in our code.

Thanks

Comment: Great question. Though you'd have to modify the third party code, this answer seems to be what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806101/is-it-possible-to-suppress-xcode-4-static-analyzer-warnings/5833430#5833430 (I haven't tried it myself, just did the research based on your question, but I plan to soon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by matthew:

```
#ifndef __clang_analyzer__ 
...
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wall"
```

See the [clang user's manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html) for other useful related #pragmas for clang.

This also works for GCC.

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wall"
```

Comment: So will that only affect the single file that it is placed in? If so, good

Comment: Tested this, and it doesn't work. Possibly this disables compiler warnings? I'm after something to disable code analysis warnings

Comment: @Chris yes, this disables compiler warnings; sorry, that's what I thought you were asking.