# false positives Xcode4 Analyzer

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, clang, clang-static-analyzer

In response to a comment made on this question: [Is it possible to suppress Xcode 4 static analyzer warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5806101/705543), here is a false positive (or at least I believe so).

The code below gives the following message:

*Although the value stored to 'action' is used in the enclosing expression, the value is never actually read from 'action'*

```
NSArray *actions = [button actionsForTarget:target forControlEvent:controlEvent];
if (actions)
{
    NSEnumerator *actionEnumerator = [actions objectEnumerator];
    NSString *action;
    while ((action = (NSString *)[actionEnumerator nextObject])) 
    {
        [button removeTarget:target action:@selector(action) forControlEvents:controlEvent];
    }
}
```

Comment: That's interesting - you should submit a bug report to Apple

Answer (score 3):

That's because when you do `@selector(action)`, it's a reference to a selector called "action".  In other words, the argument to `@selector` is parsed as a literal, not a variable.

Since the `action` variable is referring to an `NSString` naming a selector, what you want is probably:

```
[button removeTarget:target action:NSSelectorFromString(action) forControlEvents:controlEvent];
```

---

Actually, you don't even need to iterate through the actions.  A better way to do this is this one-liner:

```
[button removeTarget:target action:NULL forControlEvents:controlEvent];
```

Comment: you're right and thanks for the heads up. Other than being asleep I should read the manual more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a false positive, it is a real (**your**) bug.

`@selector(action)` describes a method with the name `action`. It does *not* describe a method with the name that is stored in the variable `action`!

The static analyzer just saved your... ;-)

Comment: I have to admit that it took me quite a while to figure out as well. Lesson is to trust the tools in 99%. :-)

Comment: Exactly! I was once the tool maker (and made the bugs in the tools ;). The mistake was stupid (on my part) but one of those that you look at it 100 times (and I did study the line of code many times before posting) and it looks right but it's wrong :( I rechecked my code and out of 279 @selectors, that was the only wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

The static analyzer is right, you don't use/read action it! `@selector()` doesn't take a NSString, so it always returns the selector for a method called action. Plus: `@selector()` is a compile time function, the compiler will replace it with a static value. Pretty much like `sizeof()` does with the size of data structures.

You should use `NSSelectorFromString()` to get a selector from an NSString.